# MacBook Pro running Windows 7 trouble sleeping

Tags: windows, mac, sleep, boot-camp

I have Windows 7 on my bootcamp partition and everything was working fine until now... now, when I close the lid, the computer doesn't go to sleep completely (fans are running)... when I reopen it, the screen remains black and I have to hard reset the machine.

Details:
when I close the lid the computer keeps running and the white LED turns on (not blinking). When I open the lid the LED turns off but the screen doesn't appear (computer is still running). Closing the lid again causes the light to turn on again and so on...

I installed the latest Win7 bootcamp drivers, updated NVidia driver with even newer version and tried to disable the MacDrive service (I suspected MacDrive could be the culprit because I installed it recently).

I ran “`sfc /scannow`” to check for and repair corrupted system files, but it also didn't help.

What else could I do? Can this be related to the fact that I'm running Windows on a Mac, or is it probably the problem in Windows (something got screwed)?

Comment: Quite likely a driver issue. Did any of them get updated recently before this started happening?

Comment: not really... I checked the list of devices and couldn't think of any that received a driver update recently... which one could be causing this besides the graphics driver? thank you

Comment: The graphics driver would be the most likely suspect. If that's not it it's difficult to track down the exact cause of something like this. See if the event log has anything to say.

Comment: Event Viewer doesn't say anything... just "Entering sleep" and "Waking up from sleep".. no errors... I guess I'll have to restore the Win7 partition from an image.. don't have the drive with the image with me right now.. in a few days I'll do it and observe at what point (if) the problem reappears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for behaviour was MacDrive Pro 9.0.5.14 after all... disabling the service was not enough.. uninstall resolved the issue as did update to v9.0.6.4

Comment: I ended my trial with MacDrive PRO and bought MacDrive Standard v9.0.6.4 and the problem is back again :s Will write to their support.

Comment: also discovered that my shutdown problem (it would halt at shutdown screen) is related to the same issue with sleeping... the issue reappeared after I installed the standard edition of MacDrive.

Comment: the acknowledged it and will issue a fix in the next version... in the meantime you can write them to get a non-final replacement .sys file